# How to inject ProducerTemplate

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I'm wondering how to properly use the @Produce annotation for a ProducerTemplate I have defined in one of my model beans.

If I add an @Autowired and this @Bean definition everything is peachy:

```
    @Bean
    ProducerTemplate producerTemplate() throws Exception {
        ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = camelContext().createProducerTemplate();
        producerTemplate.setDefaultEndpointUri("seda:workflowEntryPoint");
        return producerTemplate;
    }
```

But if I don't and only do

```
    @Produce(uri = "seda:workflowEntryPoint")
    private ProducerTemplate producer;
```

I get an NPE when trying to use it to call sendMessage(). So, what's the correct usage of the annotation?

Best,
Edoardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per camel's [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/pojo-producing.html) , it creates a proxy implementing the interface that has been annotated with `@Produce`. Can you try to have a very simple interface with just one method as suggested in the documentation. Although, your code should work but I am suspecting that the `ProducerTemplate` has plenty of methods and bcoz of that the proxy creation does not happen